# Run js or php scripts from client side on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, security

I want to know what kind of security measures I need to take if I want to create a PHP webpage on which clients can enter their javascript or php code in a textarea and submit it to the server for output. The submited javascript, however, could try to run AJAX and request server information or even try to modify them. Do I stop this in the Apache configuration file? I'd appreciate your valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

js is always run in client side, only php is run un server side (ajax=php+js)

well there are a lot things a php script could do so i suggest you to stop function and classes from your php.ini file based on what you want your clients to do
i sugest you to make that file read-only and being exeuted by a user with strict limited rights.